# Getting error while using ngbModule in angular

Tags: angular

```
Here is my module.ts code

import { NgModule,ModuleWithProviders  } from '@angular/core';'

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HeaderModule } from '../../static/header/header.module';

import { AdminDashboardModule } from '../../static/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module';

import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-tabset';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { JournalistEarningsComponent } from './journalist-earnings.component';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const routes: Routes = [{

    path: '',

    component: JournalistEarningsComponent,

  }];


@NgModule({

  imports: [

    NgbModule,

    RouterModule.forChild(routes),

    HeaderModule,

    AdminDashboardModule,

    TabsModule,

    FormsModule,

    ReactiveFormsModule,

    CommonModule

  ],
  declarations: [JournalistEarningsComponent],
})


Component.ts

page: any;

  pageSize: any

  items = [];

  constructor(

    private modalService: BsModalService,

    private router: Router,

    private httpService: LoginService,

  ) {

    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

      this.items.push({ Name: 'Shop ' + i });

    }

  }


component.html

 <table>

            <tr *ngFor="let item of items | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">

              <td>{{item.Name}}</td>

            </tr>

         </table>

         <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="items.length" [(page)]="page" [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [ellipses]="false" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
```

I am getting this error. I have tried another answer but it is not working. If any user is working on angular 8 then please provide your insight. I have also searched for ngbpagination and implemented other solutions for ngbPaginationConfig but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a Angular8 app with a component where I have a table. Table is generated via *ngFor directive. Each row of the table is an object with some fields that is being loaded from the backend when the component is initialized.

```
**StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgbPagination -> NgbPaginationConfig]: 

  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgbPagination -> NgbPaginationConfig]: 

    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbPaginationConfig!**
```

Comment: Try to import NgbPaginationModule, in your module

Answer (score 0):

You must import them module with `PaginationModule.forRoot()`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ref: [github issus](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1354#issuecomment-267974822)

Comment: These is not a correct solution and also i am using

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

and also forRoot() is depricated

Comment: Why use `forRoot()` in documentation https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/pagination ?